# SQL Server select condition

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements

I wanted to `select count (*)` from a table with condition based on type of one filed, consider below code I want something like this in one query:

```
select 
    count (*) 
from 
    moniotr as m 
case 
   when m.type = 1 
   begin 
       join paramter as p on p.id = m.paramId 
       where .....
   end
   when m.type = 2 
   begin
       join aggTable as ag on ag.id = m.addId
       where ....
```

Could you show me how to handle this in one query?

For more clearance, I want the count on monitors for those with type 1 with condition 1 and for type 2 with condition 2 , sum of those counts for two types! 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do as 2 separate query and then union the result

```
select  cnt = sum(cnt)
from
(
select  cnt = count(*)
from    monitor m
        inner join paramter as p on p.id = m.paramId 
where   m.type = 1
union all
select  cnt = count(*)
from    monitor m
        inner join aggTable as ag on ag.id = m.addId
where   m.type = 2
) as d
```

Comment: I just tried and found by myself, sorry for asking this easy question